# Solve the Differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{5x^3-xy^2-2x}{3x^2y-y^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Solve the Differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{5x^3-xy^2-2x}{3x^2y-y^3}$$

My try: Let $x^2=X$ and $y^2=Y$ we get

$xdx=dX$ and $ydy=dY$ then

$$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{5X-Y-2}{3X-Y}$$ which is a Non homogenous Differential equation.Is there any formal approach to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Make the $(u,v)$ substittion. Such that you have at the numerator $au+bv$ and at the denominator $cu+dv$ , where $a,b,c,d$ are constants. We want to have this form:
$$\frac {dv}{du}=\frac {au+bv}{cu+dv}$$

For this purpose , we try this substitution $$X=u+a$$ $$Y=v+b$$ 
After basic calculation, we get $(a,b)=(1,3)$ and therefore :
$$X=u+1$$
$$Y=v+3$$

The equation becomes
$$\frac {dv}{du}=\frac {5u-v}{3u-v}$$

This equation is homogeneous. Susbtitute 
$$v=tu \implies v'=t'u+t $$

Comment: It may be helpful to describe why you chose those substitutions. Otherwise, the OP will need to ask a new question for every DE of this form.

Comment: you 're right @AlexanderJ93